# How to print HTML file from command-line in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, printing, html

How to print HTML file from command line in Ubuntu
when I run the below command it only prints the content of the HTML file, not the rendered content.

```
lp template.html -d TVS_MSP-250CH-custom
```

Comment: It is quite normal that `lp` prints the text that is in the file, without further processing.

Answer (score 2):

The `lp` command considers your html as a text file. You will first need to render the HTML to a file which CUPS recognizes and interprets, i.e.,  PostScript, PDF, and image files besides text.

`htmldoc` can generate postscript or PDF output of HTML (Install with `sudo apt install htmldoc`). `pandoc` can also be used.